# DB2 CASE statement and CONCAT

Tags: db2

I'm having trouble return the correct information with my select statement

table:

```
prefix | suffix | alternate
------ | ------ | --------
A      | 12345  | 0
B      | 67890  | 0
C      | 0      | 555555
```

Here is my query

```
SELECT 
        CASE WHEN prefix = 'C' THEN alternate
        ELSE CONCAT(prefix, suffix) END as Result
FROM table
```

What I would like to see as a result:

```
Result
------
A12345
B67890
555555
```

What I actually see:

```
555555
```

if I take out the CONCAT using this select

```
SELECT 
        CASE WHEN prefix = 'C' THEN alternate
        ELSE suffix END as Result
FROM table
```

I get the number of rows I want but not the correct column values.  I'm missing the prefix in the first two rows.

Result

```
12345
67890
555555
```

Thoughts on how I can do this without duplicating code with union?

```
Select concat(prefix,suffix) as result from table
union
select alternate as result from table
```

Comment: Can you try: `select prefix || case when prefix = 'C' then combined else suffix end as result from table`?

Comment: There's really no way for that query to go from three rows to just one row. Are you sure that's the output?

Comment: that is the actual output I'm getting. table column names, results are changed to protect the innocent of course.   I just don't see why it wouldn't work.  CASE allows you to display different columns based on what's in the WHEN and CONCAT allows for multiple columns to be combined into one.  I also changed my example a bit just to be clear.  For each row if the prefixs is a "C", I want to return what's in the combined column.  If it's not a C, I want to return a CONCAT of prefix and suffix.   Is this not possible?

Comment: Why don't you try a `JOIN` between a `SELECT CONCAT(PREFIX, SUFFIX) WHEN PREFIX != 'C'` and a `SELECT ALTERNATE WHEN PREFIX = 'C'`?

Comment: Yes, it's very easy and you're clearly on the right track. There's clearly a piece of information missing. Could NULLs be part of the picture?

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN prefix <> 'C' 
         THEN prefix||suffix 
         ELSE cast (alternate as char(20)) 
    END as Result
FROM table
```